# How to print check to release using API

Tags: api, printing, acumatica

I am integrating Acumatica using REST API, I am able to create check but not able to change the check status from pending print to print.
Can anyone help me to know how to change check status to print

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manually update the status value through the api (you can tell because the API does not allow you to edit an entity any differently than you can through the screen). You have to invoke the Print check action (which is not present on the default endpoint). I extended the default endpoint to include the action

[image]

Unfortunatly the api was unable to handle the redirect required exception after the report ran.

I did however, manage to print checks using the Process Payments / Print Checks through the api:

I created a new endpoint for the process payments / print checks screen
[image]

And Added an action with a parameter for payment method on the header, and the action invokes 'Process All'

[image]

It succesfully marked all checks with the payment method "CHECK" as printed

[image]

Comment: I followed same step getting error **"exceptionMessage": "The Process All button is disabled.",**

Comment: I resolved above problem by fixing my param names, now this is working

Comment: Can you please help me find the way how print/process single check by ReferenceNbr or is there any other way to print/process individual check

Comment: but this solution not going to work, as I have 10000 Acumatica customers and I can not create this endpoint manually, is there any way I can create this endpoint using some API

Comment: You can put the endpoint into a customization and publish to multiple sites

Comment: can you please share any doc that allows to publish to multiple sites, or if any step by step guide that help. thanks

Comment: I want to publish that API to other multiple sites using some code, I will be having access token of every customer but not UI access. So can you please share the way of publishing this kind of extension to any customer